# Get necessary authorization for my iOS App

Tags: swift, app-store

I have my API Client(an iOS application) that shows videos for a specific YouTube channel. When the user starts the app, my client fetches all the videos from a specific channel using the channel id. The user can see videos to the channel in a table view and watch them if they click one in the table view. I am not monetizing these videos, no adds, no anything. I am not making money in any aspect of this app.

When submitting my app, Apple is saying that I do not have the neccesary authorization to show this data in my app because I am not the "content owner." Is there specific YouTube API Services documentation that I can gather for them to show the authorization? Also, will I have to get approval from the content creator (specific YouTube channel) to show this data?

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: No answers yet, just requested access from the content owner.